# How to check if a string is built up using only specific characters

Tags: c#, string

I need to check if a string is only built up using 1, 0 and comma. It should also starts with either 0 or 1 and also ends with 0 or 1:

The checking for start and end can be done like this (Or if you think it can be improved peplase let me know!)

```
if ((text.StartsWith("0") || text.StartsWith("1")) //Starts with 0 or 1
    && (text.EndsWith("0") || text.EndsWith("1")) //Ends with 0 or 1
    && //How to check if it only has 0, 1 and comma?            )
{
    //Do Something!
}
```

Comment: you can accomplish this using regex.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Regex`, try this:

```
if (new Regex("^[01][01,]*[01]$").Match(text).Success)
{
   // do your stuffs
}
```

Comment: This works well, though maybe it's worth noting that it isn't  necessary to instantiate a new Regex, leading to a less trainwreck-like result. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8589299/1106367)

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool CheckMyString(string text)
{
    if ((text.StartsWith("0") || text.StartsWith("1")) 
       && (text.EndsWith("0") || text.EndsWith("1")))
    {
      foreach (char c in text)
      {
         if (c != "1" && c != "0" && c != ",")
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression like this [01][01,]+?[01]. Im sure there could be better regex patterns to use. But that would work.

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(mystring, "[01][01,]+?[01]"))
   //yes it matches;
```

This regex pattern will look for a 0 or a 1 and then an optional sequence of 0, 1 or "," and then ending in a 0 or a 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("0101,1010", "^[01][01,]*[01]$"))
{
     doSomething();
}
```

you need to add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

to the top of your file for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it one way ?

```
if (value.Trim("01,".ToCharArray()).Length == 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[01][01,]+?[01]");
if (!reg.IsMatch("3452"))
{
    Response.Write("Does Not Match");
}

if (reg.IsMatch("01111,1"))
{
    Response.Write("Yes Match!");
}
```